# not showing custom type meta box

Tags: custom-post-types

Here is my custom type post code. I want to add the meta box in there...

```
function events_cust(){
      $label = array(
            'name' => _x('Events'),
            'singular_name' => _x('events'),
            'menu_name'  => __('Events'),
            'add_new' => __('Add Event'),
            'add_new_item' => __ ('Add New Event'),
            'all_item' => __('All Event'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
            'new_item' => __('New Event'),
            'view_item' => __('View Event'),
            'update_item' => __('update Event'),
            'search_item' => __('Search Event')
            );
            $attr = array(
            'label' => __('Events'),
            'description' => __('Event'),
            'labels' => $label,
            'supports'  => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
            'taxonomies' => array('genres'),
            'hiecrarhical' => false,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_adim_bar' => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
   'can_export'          => true,
   'has_archive'         => true,
   'exclude_from_search' => false,
   'publicly_queryable'  => true,
   'capability_type'     => 'post',
            );
            register_post_type('events-lists',$attr);
      }
      add_action( 'init', 'events_cust', 0 );

   add_action('add_meta_boxes','create_events_metaboxes');
   function create_events_metaboxes(){
      add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists','normal','hight');
   }

   function show_events_metaboxes(){
    echo 'Hello Meta box';
   }
```

What's wrong with us.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','create_events_metaboxes'); 
function create_events_metaboxes() { 
  add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists'); 
}

function show_events_metaboxes($post){ echo 'Hello Meta box'; }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Refer from [add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

Comment: You are missing one argument $context.Try add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists','normal','high','height'); code.

Comment: content argument already applied(normal)......

Comment: Sorry i got you.Your $priority argument is wrong its "high" instead of "hight".

Comment: i'm cheak the all add_meta_box argument .....What it's not working

Comment: I try `add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists','normal','high');`  and its working.

Comment: what's wrong with us..........

Comment: Check your last line: 

Your Code
`add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists','normal','hight');`


My Code:
`add_meta_box('events-meta-box','Events Details','show_events_metaboxes','events-lists','normal','hi‌​gh');`

Last arguement is "high". You used "hight"

Answer (score 0):

[ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) may help in your farther run. Try it if you need meta boxes more organised.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function event_custom_meta_boxes( $post_type, $post ) {
        add_meta_box( 
            'my-meta-box',
            __( 'My Meta Box' ),
            'render_my_meta_box',
            'post', //post type, event, product etc. 
            'normal',
            'default'
        );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'event_custom_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );

  function render_my_meta_box(){
    echo "Hello World!";
  }
```

for more reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes